# Memory leak in child process. How to handle memory in child processes

Tags: c, fork, execve

I'am writting a terminal and using the following function to execute a command :

```
void    execute_input(t_list *node, char **envp)
{
    int     pid1;
    int     status;

    if (ft_lstsize(node) > 1)
        command_chain(node);
    else if (is_builtin(node))
        execute_builtin(node);
    else
    {
        get_data()->executing_cmd = 1;
        pid1 = fork();
        if (pid1 == 0)
        {
            if (!access(node->token[0], X_OK))
                node->path = node->token[0];
            execve(node->path, node->token, envp);
            exit(errno);
        }
        waitpid(pid1, &status, 0);
        if (WIFEXITED(status))
            get_data()->exit = WEXITSTATUS(status);
        get_data()->executing_cmd = 0;
    }
}
```

`node->path` and `node->token` were dynamically allocated in the parent.

When my execve returns -1 because he was unable to execute the program, I will have some weird memory leaks that I can't solve.

I don't know how to approach this situation. I have tried freeing the memory in the child process after execve but that will result in invalid free.

How should handle in the child process the memory that was allocaed in the parent process?

Comment: Memory should be handled in the child process like it would in any process: Free or destroy all resources you allocate or create. And remember that your child process starts as an almost exact copy of the parent process. That includes things like open files and memory.

Comment: Once you `fork()` your "child" process "owns" all of the allocations within that child process. They're no longer from the parent.

Comment: How does a "memory leak" relate to `execve()` failing?

Comment: I know that I only get the leak once ```execve()``` has failed. If it has executed the command sucessfully I don't have a leak.

Comment: With that said, I believe your question really is more about the `exec` call, and what happens with all resources on that call. For that please see [the `execve` manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).

Comment: And yes, if `exec` fails, nothing special happens. Your process will continue as normal with the next statement. Since you directly call `exit` the normal process termination will commence. By the way, you should really report that the `exec` call failed.

Comment: I think that the issue is that when ```execve``` is sucessfull I dont even have to worry about the memory handling because execve() replaces its entire memory space with the new program specified in the exec call. The child process essentially becomes a completely different program, and any memory allocated in the parent process prior to the fork() will not be accessible or deallocated in the child process.

Comment: But when ```execve``` fails I think I should free the memory myself and when I do it I start getting invalid frees.

Comment: Re “I think that the issue is that when `execve` is sucessfull I dont even have to worry about the memory handling because execve() replaces its entire memory space with the new program specified in the exec call”: Since completely abandoning everything about the old program is acceptable when `execve` is successful, it should also be acceptable when exiting due to `execve` failing. In neither case will you manually release resources; both cases leave them to the operating system to deal with, and that is fine.

Answer (score 2):

If `execve` fails, you're going to exit the child process immediately [technically you should be doing this with `_exit` instead of with `exit`, but don't worry about that right now].

When you exit the child process, the operating system deallocates *all* the resources allocated to it, including everything allocated by `malloc`.

Therefore, it is unnecessary to free anything explicitly in the child process.

Comment: While it's true that the OS will free everything, memory leak detectors will still detect is as memory leaks. Cleaning up after oneself is, IMO, The Right Thing To Do™ :)

Comment: I have done it , but then why will valgrind complain about leaks of memory that I have allocated in the parent process ? And the parent process is still running !!

= 5 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 72
=    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
===    by 0x10DEBD: ft_strdup (in /home/simao/Desktop/Minishell_delivery/minishell)
=    by 0x10A3C7: new_list_token (scanner.c:29)
=    by 0x10A59A: parse (scanner.c:88)
===    by 0x109EB0: get_user_input (read.c:28)
    by 0x1095FF: main (m_sh.c:27)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Adding code and workload because some tool wants it and not because it helps the user or the programmer is putting the cart before the horse. It is wasteful of labor and of computing resources. The tool serves us; we do not serve the tool.

Comment: @zwol: I suspect you mean `_Exit`, not `_exit`.

Comment: @Simao, Valgrind does not complain of the child about memory allocated by the parent, but it may well complain about *the child's copies* of memory allocated by the parent.  These are distinct.  if you are satisfied that you `execve()` promptly in every `fork()`ed child, and that you exit immediately whenever an `execve()` fails, then simply do not enable Valgrind's `--trace-children` option, which is off by default anyway.

Comment: I have found out, that when excve() fails I must manually free the memory in my child process and that the issue here is that actually on of the free functions I wrote was wrong. And I no longer have leaks but I had an invalid free because I was acessing the same block of memory.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Speak not of this ISO C NIH-ism to me.

Comment: @Simao I would argue that it is _incorrect_ to free any allocation made by the parent process on the child side of a `fork` performed with the intention to call `execve`, despite what a leak checker may be telling you.

Comment: "still reachable" is not a memory leak.